# Sum calculation of excel column - PHP Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to store sum of columns in a cell .The column is dynamically created.So I can't use the formula

> =SUM(K8:K894)

in

```
    for($k=9;count($columns);$k++){      
         $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($k,4,'=SUM(K8:K894)');
     }
```

Please give me a solution.Please see my screenshot.I need to show the sum of column col1,col2,col3 just 1 row above the headers.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to know from which column your data will start? I mean to know the column No. from where data will start?

Comment: Yes.It is possible

Comment: And the column no, where you want to show the total value is also fixed?

Comment: row is fixed.Column is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the `for` loop.
You can try this: (assuming you want to add value from K8 to some dynamic value)

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue("<Your Column No from where you want to THE SUM VALUE>",
       "=SUM(<Your Column No from where you want to start adding i.e K>8:<Your Column No from where you want to start adding i.e K>".count($columns).")")
);
```

Comment: =SUM(K8:K894) give the sum from cell K8 to K894 right?But I didnt get the value K since it is dynamically created.

Comment: My columns are dynamically created.We can use $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($k,4,'value');  for dynmically created columns.Then how can implement sum for the same?

Comment: as you know the column no & start row put it dynamically instead of fixed value